# Grid Snap tool in babylon js for proper wall construction

Tags: babylonjs

I would like to implement a snap grid function in my pointer, but it seems when I zoom in or out, the grid distance changes. Is there a solution for this?

Here is the playground: https://playground.babylonjs.com/#VHW8N9#2

I created the grid using this

```
scene.pick(Math.round(scene.pointerX/100)*100, Math.round(scene.pointerY/100)*100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found a solution for this in this playground, https://playground.babylonjs.com/#VHW8N9#3.
If someone is facing the same issue, this may help.